# Xamarin forms C#, How to make the label change value in a listview?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My code and listview works fine (no errors and I get the label in my listview), but when I click on my stepper I want the value of my label I created to change in the listview. Now it doesn't do anything. Check out the code below.

My xaml:

```
<Stepper Minimum="0" Maximum="10" Increment="0.1" ValueChanged="OnStepperValueChanged" />

    <Label Text="{Binding Amount}" />
```

My listview code is all figured out and I add my public class string in my listview that I give a value of 0.

```
public class theInfo 
{
    public string Amount { get; set; }
}

myList.Add (new theInfo () {Amount = "0" }); //i add this in my listviewcode. it works, I get 0 in my listview on every created row.

async void OnStepperValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    new theInfo () {Amount = string.Format ("Stepper value is {0:F1}", e.NewValue) }; //I reckon I have to convert Amount to a label.text somehow?
}
```